# How do I display clickable search results, line by line

Tags: tkinter, sqlite, python-3.4

I am working on a programming project for A Level Computer Science,a database which allow the user to add, edit, search and delete recipes in an SQL database, using SQLite3 in Python and Tkinter as a GUI.  I am fairly new to SQL and tkinter.

I am currently working on the search function, which is supposed to take a user's inputted search term in an entry widget.
In response the program should display recipe names which includes the search terms, and the type of the 3 ingredients used in the said recipe.  The results should ideally appear line by line.

I have looked at a similar question at 
[How to output results from a sqlite3 query on seperate rows in a tkinter GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648622/how-to-output-results-from-a-sqlite3-query-on-seperate-rows-in-a-tkinter-gui),
but the snag is that I would like to make each result clickable so that when a result is clicked, it will open the same window as the one for adding a recipe, but with the dtails for the recipe already filled in.

(I have resorted to using just 3 ingredients due to time constraints; my teacher wants to see working code by the end of the week)

Initially, I received an ambiguous column name error which I assumed was the lack of aliases in the query.  So I put some in as shown in the SELECT query above, and now I get the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\ComputingAlevel\CompProject\PROJECT.py", line 84, in search_byrecipe
    WHERE ? in recipe''',(search)) #06/03/17 must use recipe
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: ingredients_list.type
```

The thing is, there is definitely a column called type in the table ingredients_list, so I am stuck.  How would I work around this, and if corrected would this actually display clickable search results line by line?

[This is the main window.  The space above the button and entry widgets is where I would like the search results displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VsCE.jpg)

I'm sorry that the question is long-winded, I'm not sure what the minimum required detail is for such a question.

Update: I have removed the code for the tables and here is the stripped down GUI code as requested:

```
def search_byrecipe():  #03/03/17
    search = a.get() 
    query = conn.execute('''
    SELECT recipe.name AS rn,ingredients_list.type AS il
    FROM recipe
    LEFT JOIN recipe AS r ON ingredients_list.ingredient = recipe.ingredient1
    LEFT JOIN recipe AS r2 ON ingredients_list.ingredient = recipe.ingredient2
    LEFT JOIN recipe AS r3 ON ingredients_list.ingredient = recipe.ingredient3
    WHERE ? in recipe''',(search)) 
    list1 = conn.fetchall()

    result = cursor.fetchone()

    print(result)
    output = '\n'.join([' '.join(row) for row in list1])

    master.insert(tkinter.END, output)
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what your real problem is. Are you asking how to solve the database problems (`no such column: ingredients_list.type`), or are you asking  how to display results in a GUI? If the former, you don't need any of the GUI code to reproduce, and if the latter you don't need any of the database code to reproduce. You might want to read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First and foremost I would like help with the GUI on displaying results because the error was something that occurred as a result of my attempt to display them.

Comment: Sorry if I was being unclear, and thanks for your help.

Comment: If the problem is with displaying results in a GUI, please rework your example to not include the database code. Just hard-code two or three lines of results with just two or three columns.